# SQL: Calculating Rates Within Percentiles

Tags: sql, r

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table - I simulated a local SQL Netezza connection within R to upload this table:

```
set.seed(123)
num_rows <- 100
gender <- sample(c("m", "f"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
disease <- sample(c("y", "n"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
income <- runif(num_rows, min = 1000, max = 10000)
my_table <- data.frame(gender, disease, income)


library(DBI)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, my_table)
```

**My Question:**  Using Netezza SQL, I want to calculate 20 different ranges of income (i.e. ntiles), and calculate the disease rate within each of these ranges.

Here is my attempt to do this (this can be run in R):

```
q = "WITH ntiles AS (
    SELECT 
income,
 disease, 
NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY income) as income_ntile
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT 
income_ntile, 
MIN(income) as min_income, 
MAX(income) as max_income,
    COUNT(*) as count, COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END) as disease_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END)*100.0/COUNT(*) as disease_rate
FROM ntiles
GROUP BY income_ntile;"

dbGetQuery(con, q)
```

The output is in the right format:

```
   income_ntile min_income max_income count disease_count disease_rate
1             1   1056.707   1648.514    10             5           50
2             2   1669.461   2545.286    10             5           50
3             3   2549.546   3347.712    10             4           40
4             4   3407.693   4556.981    10             5           50
5             5   4563.034   5244.186    10             4           40
6             6   5300.608   6188.671    10             5           50
7             7   6337.411   7177.376    10             4           40
8             8   7284.354   8067.625    10             5           50
9             9   8189.485   8937.798    10             4           40
10           10   9241.152   9839.263    10             5           50
```

But I am not sure if I have written the logic correctly.

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly**

Thanks!

Comment: Yep. The SQL query is correct.