# SQL: Does the Partition Order Change the Results of a Query?

Tags: sql, partitioning, netezza

I am working with Netezza SQL.

I have the following table (that I created with R and uploaded to a simulated Netezza SQL connection):

```
set.seed(123)
num_rows <- 10000
gender <- sample(c("m", "f"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
country <- sample(c("canada", "usa", "mexico"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
favorite_color <- sample(c("red", "blue", "green"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
disease <- sample(c("y", "n"), num_rows, replace = TRUE)
income <- runif(num_rows, min = 1000, max = 10000)
my_table <- data.frame(gender, country, favorite_color, disease, income)
my_table$id = 1:nrow(my_table)

library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, my_table)

  gender country favorite_color disease   income id
1      m  mexico           blue       n 8857.846  1
2      m  canada            red       n 2706.397  2
3      m     usa          green       y 7560.036  3
4      f     usa          green       y 6539.031  4
5      m  mexico          green       n 3350.300  5
6      f     usa          green       y 9979.646  6
```

I have the following query which (I think) calculates the disease rate within different income percentiles (e.g. by groups of 5 percentiles, i.e. 5 x 20 = 100):

```
q = "WITH ntiles AS (
    SELECT 
income,
 disease, 
NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY income) as income_ntile
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT 
income_ntile, 
MIN(income) as min_income, 
MAX(income) as max_income,
    COUNT(*) as count, COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END) as disease_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END)*100.0/COUNT(*) as disease_rate
FROM ntiles
GROUP BY income_ntile;"

dbGetQuery(con, q)


   income_ntile min_income max_income count disease_count disease_rate
1             1   1001.761   1927.232  1000           500         50.0
2             2   1930.096   2817.335  1000           513         51.3
3             3   2819.809   3685.053  1000           508         50.8
4             4   3685.592   4569.439  1000           487         48.7
5             5   4570.365   5501.732  1000           484         48.4
6             6   5501.850   6425.699  1000           526         52.6
7             7   6426.975   7350.247  1000           499         49.9
8             8   7351.599   8222.136  1000           493         49.3
9             9   8223.823   9120.188  1000           474         47.4
10           10   9120.347   9997.922  1000           513         51.3
```

**My Question:** Suppose I want to add other variables to this query (i.e. have the disease rate not only based on income percentiles - but other variables as well):

```
q2 = "WITH ntiles AS (
    SELECT 
        income,
        gender,
        country,
        favorite_color,
        disease, 
        NTILE(20) OVER (PARTITION BY gender, country, favorite_color ORDER BY income) as income_ntile
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT 
    income_ntile, 
    gender,
    country,
    favorite_color,
    MIN(income) as min_income, 
    MAX(income) as max_income,
    COUNT(*) as count, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END) as disease_count,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN disease = 'y' THEN 1 END)*100.0/COUNT(*) as disease_rate
FROM ntiles
GROUP BY income_ntile, gender, country, favorite_color;"

dbGetQuery(con, q2)
```

In general, does it matter whether you change the partition order? E.g. `PARTITION BY gender, country, favorite_color ORDER BY income)` vs `PARTITION BY country, gender, favorite_color ORDER BY income)` ? Will any change in order still produce the same query?

Thanks!

Comment: The order of the columns in a `PARTITION BY` clause does not matter. Same as with `GROUP BY`. You can state the columns in any order; the result remains the same.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner: Thank you so much for your reply! Can you please take a look at this related question if you have time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76632957/sql-calculating-rates-within-percentiles